# Modify Contact Form 7 Submission Data

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using Contact Form 7 on a site and need to alter the checkbox submitted data. The checkbox has a label called 'Tick here if you dont want to receive further marketing', when this is checked the value sent in the admins notification email displays the checkbox label.
So it looks like:

Tick here if you dont want to receive further marketing: Tick here if you dont want to receive further marketing

I want to alter it so when its checked the value posted is No.

I believe I can use the following action hook to achieve this but I dont know how to check if the checkbox has been ticked within this function and modify its value.

Any help much appreciated.

```
// define the wpcf7_posted_data callback 
function action_wpcf7_posted_data( $array ) { 
// make action magic happen here... 
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'wpcf7_posted_data', 'action_wpcf7_posted_data', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 9):

I believe you can just use:

```
// define the wpcf7_posted_data callback 
function action_wpcf7_posted_data( $array ) { 
    //'checkbox-name' is the name that you gave the field in the CF7 admin.
    $value = $array['checkbox-name'];
    if( !empty( $value ) ){
        $array['checkbox-name'] = "New Value";
    }

    return $array;
}; 
add_filter( 'wpcf7_posted_data', 'action_wpcf7_posted_data', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working but its also changing the posted data when the checkbox **isn't** ticked. When its not ticked I'd want it to either send no data or say Yes.

Comment: I'd say that you are using the wrong hook. I'll look up the right one tomorrow.

Comment: Should I be using wpcf7_before_send_mail? Will the if statement from above work as intended with it?

Comment: On second thought, checking for a blank string may not be correct. Find out what the value of $value is when the checkbox isn't ticked. Whatever that value is replace the blank string in the if statement with that.

Comment: I'm not sure how to find that out?

Comment: You can echo out the value.

Comment: Could you please post some code to explain?. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the code. Instead of looking for an empty string I'm using the "empty" php function.

Comment: Thanks for the code, just test it but its staying outputting No even when checkbox not ticked. Heres the actual code I'm using:

Comment: '// define the wpcf7_posted_data callback 
function action_wpcf7_posted_data( $array ) { 
    //'checkbox-name' is the name that you gave the field in the CF7 admin.
    $value = $array['further-marketing'];
    if( !empty( $value ) ){
        $array['further-marketing'] = "No";
    }

    return $array;
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'wpcf7_posted_data', 'action_wpcf7_posted_data', 10, 1 );'

Comment: Any more help would be really appreciated

Comment: Although this post is rather old, I ran into the same problem and here is the solution: the $value of the checkbox-name in the posted-data will always be an array and thus non empty. The difference is that the first element is either empty or not. So the correct check is: `if (!empty( $value[0]) )`. and then `$array['checkbox-name'][0] = "New Value";`

Comment: is there any way to through error and not submitting form if minimum 3 checkbox are not checked

Comment: life saver!! @Fencer04

Comment: Working perfectly !! Thank you