# Modify Contact Form 7 Submission Data for multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, contact-form-7

This topic was also handled in: [Modify Contact Form 7 Submission Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000543/modify-contact-form-7-submission-data/49918220#49918220)

The link above got me somewhere but no cigar (excuse my english).

My CF7 form contains a couple of checkboxes. After submitting the form the user gets a mail where links related to checkbox context are provided if checkbox was checked.

The following function changes checkbox related data on form submit - in this case for the particular checkbox the wanted data would be "some url here".

```
// define the wpcf7_posted_data callback 
function action_wpcf7_posted_data( $array ) { 
    //'checkbox-name' is the name that you give the field in the CF7 admin.
    $value = $array['checkbox-name'];    
     if( !empty( $value[0])  ){
      $array['checkbox-name'][0] = "some url here";      
    } 
    return $array;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_posted_data', 'action_wpcf7_posted_data', 10, 1 );
```

The above code works fine for a single checkbox but what if I have multiple checkboxes.

Is it possible to use multidimensional arrays there for example?

Thanks in advance