# How to add text on image dynamically in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

while using contact form 7 there is attribute called Team name, so when a person enters team name in form and uploads the image, then how to add logo and the team name to the picture then send?
Pictures are sending but the the logo and the text are not paste as watermark on the picture.

The question is , **how to add dynamically the text and logo on image, when some one uploads a picture in contact form 7, and then send it.**

*NOTE:*  I used Image watermark and easy watermark plugin but they didn't work

```
<div class="clearfix"> 
 <div id="left"> 
   <label>Team Name [text* text-145 class:cf7-fa-icon-fa-users ]</label> 
   <label> Player Name* [text* your-name class:cf7-fa-icon-fa-male ]</label> 
 </div> 
 <div id="right"> 
  <label>Time [number* number-1 class:scorebox]</label> 
  <label>Player Email* [email* your-email class:cf7-fa-icon-fa-envelope] </br> 
  Group Image [file* file-303 limit:104857600 class:upload-btn-wrapper class:btn] </br></br>[submit "Send"] 
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I think your question is too broad. please show us a sample of what u have done

Comment: when some one upload a picture in contact form 7 to send it, how dynamically name should paste on the picture as watermark in  wordpress form.. That's the question

Comment: please add your code to the question if possible and tag the language u use in tags

Comment: <div class="clearfix"> 
 <div id="left">
 <label>Team Name
     [text* text-145 class:cf7-fa-icon-fa-users  ]</label>
<label> Player Name*
    [text* your-name class:cf7-fa-icon-fa-male ]</label> 
 </div>
<div id="right">
 <label>Time
  [number* number-1  class:scorebox]</label>
 <label>Player Email*
    [email* your-email class:cf7-fa-icon-fa-envelope]
 </br>

  Group Image
   [file* file-303 limit:104857600 class:upload-btn-wrapper class:btn]
</br></br>[submit "Send"]
  </div>
</div>

Comment: mean when i want to send an image while uploading the image how can logo and team name paste as water mark on the picture... as you can see the team name enter randomly.. then how can paste the team name on the picture before sending through mail,,

Comment: i guess you are storing the form-data with some plugin into the wordpress database, as well as add the image to the media-collection?

for creating a watermark text there is good functionality within php. here is a example:
http://consistentcoder.com/add-a-text-watermark-to-an-image-with-php
http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagestring.php

you will have to do this, after the form has been sent. use the hook wpcf7_mail_sent eg:
// ...in functions.php
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', function ($cf7) {
    // Run code after the email has been sent
});

Comment: i just noticed that you actually want to email the data directly, not for storage in wordpress. then you have to hook/filter somewhere else. check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000543/modify-contact-form-7-submission-data

Answer (score 0):

You can use wp-forms for this task 
because it solve not problem you .

it decrease your time

Comment: wp-form can paste the logo and text as watermark on the uploaded picture,,,,?

Comment: No when i want to send an image to other the image should have paste their name which i was also entering in form,