# Contact Form 7 (CF7) radio button to change User Role on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a form setup for users to fill in after they register on my WordPress site. Ive setup the form using Contact Form 7, and have a radio button called radio-766 that has two options: subscriber and customer.

I want the user to pick one of these two options, then when they submit the form, it will change their user role.

Below is what I have so far... I've grabbed snippets from online and tried to create my own, but it isn't working. Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

```
function tm_cf7_roles_posted_data( $posted_data ) {

    // Stop if user is not logged in.
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    ob_start();

    $role = sanitize_key( $posted_data['radio-766'] );
    if ( ! in_array( $role, array( 'subscriber', 'customer' ) ) )
        return;

    $user = new WP_User( get_current_user_id() );
    $index = key( $user->roles );
    $user_role = $user->roles[ $index ];


    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
} 
add_action( 'wpcf7_posted_data', 'tm_cf7_roles_posted_data' );
```

Should I be including the form name or ID anywhere? Can't find info on this

Any help is so appreciated!

***EDIT***

I feel like there is nothing connecting this function to the CF7 form named "After LinkedIn", so I found this snippet of code, just not sure how to integrate and get working

```
if (!isset($cfdata->posted_data) && class_exists('WPCF7_Submission')) {
        // Contact Form 7 version 3.9 removed $cfdata->posted_data and now
        // we have to retrieve it from an API
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        if ($submission) {
            $formdata = $submission->get_posted_data();
        }
    } elseif (isset($cfdata->posted_data)) {
        // For pre-3.9 versions of Contact Form 7
        $formdata = $cfdata->posted_data;
    } else {
        // We can't retrieve the form data
        return $cfdata;
    }
      // Check this is the user registration form
    if ( $cfdata->title() == 'After LinkedIn') {
```

Comment: Make sure that your function tm_cf7_roles_posted_data is invoking after form submission ?

Comment: can you print $role here

Comment: Hey @ajith and jinesh thanks for the responses... how exactly do i do these things? I am not sure what to add

Comment: @Kiki Can you check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000543/modify-contact-form-7-submission-data

Comment: Thanks @ajith, I tried to use some info from that post now too but it didnt work either. I just updated my question with some more info if that helps at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Contact form 7 plugin author `is_user_logged_in()` will work on below to cases in form submission:

1. `subscribers_only: true` set in the additional setting in form. **OR**
2. Set `WPCF7_VERIFY_NONCE` to true using `add_filter( 'wpcf7_verify_nonce', '__return_true' );`

For more information [click here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-user-id-when-form-is-submitted/).

Also, to change the user role you can do the following:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_posted_data', 'tm_cf7_roles_posted_data' );
function tm_cf7_roles_posted_data( $posted_data ) {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $wpcf7      = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();

    $formID = $wpcf7->id();
    if ( $submission ) {
        if( $formID == "YOUR-FORM-ID" ) {
            if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                $role = sanitize_key( $posted_data['radio-766'][0] );
                if ( ! in_array( $role, array( 'subscriber', 'customer' ) ) )
                    return;

                // Getting the WP_User object
                $user = wp_get_current_user();
                // The user exists
                if( $user && $user->exists() ) {
                    // Check if user already has that role or not
                    if ( !in_array( $role, (array) $user->roles ) ) {
                        // Remove all the previous roles from the user and add this one
                        // This will also reset all the caps and set them for the new role
                        $user->set_role( $role );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you only want to add a new role to the user and retain the existing role then instead of `set_role` use below:

```
// Add a new role to the user while retaining the previous ones
$user->add_role( $role );
```

Answer (score 1):

As for programatically setting a user role you can just take the user object and use the set_role() function to change their role to whatever you want as long as that role has been defined.Try this way

```
function tm_cf7_roles_posted_data( $posted_data ) {

    // Stop if user is not logged in.
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        return;

    ob_start();

    $role = sanitize_key( $_POST['radio-766'] );
    if ( ! in_array( $role, array( 'subscriber', 'customer' ) ) )
        return;

    $user = new WP_User( get_current_user_id() );
    $index = key( $user->roles );
    $user_role = $user->set_role($role);


    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
} 
add_action( 'wpcf7_posted_data', 'tm_cf7_roles_posted_data' );
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for this, but it doesnt work either :( .... I think there is still something missing in correlating the radio options from the CF7 form

Comment: can you print $role so I can know you get proper value or not? and please check my answer I have updated it

Comment: Maybe this will help... this is the original post I got the details from: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240230/how-to-allow-registered-users-to-change-their-user-role-through-frontend 

This works and changes the roles correctly, it is now when I try to change the select to CF7 that it doesnt work.

Comment: Is it possible to share your website url? echo  $role = sanitize_key( $_POST['radio-766'] );

Comment: Unfortunately not, its locally hosted. When I print the role in this code nothing shows. Im going to update my quesiton with another snippet of code I found that connects directly to the CF7 form

Comment: can you print_r$(_POST) in your function tm_cf7_roles_posted_data

Comment: I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$' in /localhost/kap/wp-content/themes/listify-child/functions.php on line 230

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203653/discussion-between-kiki-and-jinesh).

Comment: hello have you check my comment