# Update Contact Form FormData

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

Hi I am using following code to change the form data value of Contact Form 7 :

i want to update the value how can i do that?

Hi I am using following code to change the form data value of Contact Form 7 :

```
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_do_something_else");

function wpcf7_do_something_else($cf7) {

$wpcf = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();

// get form data
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

if ($submission) {
    // get submitted data
    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data()['phone-271'];
    $submission->get_posted_data()['phone-271'] = "456464646";

    // Output the form data to the browser console
    // echo '\<script\>console.log(' . $posted_data . ')\</script\>';
}

return $wpcf;
```

}

i want to update the value how can i do that?`

Comment: This question has already been answered over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000543/modify-contact-form-7-submission-data)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify Contact Form 7 Submission Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000543/modify-contact-form-7-submission-data)

Answer (score 0):

Here is code, how can you achieve

```
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_do_something_else");

function wpcf7_do_something_else($cf7) {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if ($submission) {
    
        $posted_data = &$submission->get_posted_data();

        
        if (isset($posted_data['phone-271'])) {
            
            $posted_data['phone-271'] = "456464646";

            // Optional: Output the original form data to the browser console
            // echo '<script>console.log(' . json_encode($posted_data) . ')</script>';
        }
    }

    return $cf7;
}
```